# Is there a ES6 shortcut way to compare array of elements and object key and remove the non-matching elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find a shortcut or single line of code that can active following:

I have a array `selectedFields` consisting of elements:

```
selectedFields = [ "time", "age", "city" ]
```

I have a object `valueProvided` consisting of values:

```
valueProvided = { "time": "2022-10-01", "visa": "onArrival", "age": 30, "city": "paris", "hotel": "Holiday" }
```

I would like to compare the 2 fields and remove any elements from `valueProvided object` that are not available in the array. Meaning in this case the elements `visa` and `hotel` are not present within `selectedFields` so I would like to remove it from `valueProvided` so my final result would look something like this:

```
result = { "time": "2022-10-01",  "age": 30, "city": "paris" }
```

I am aware that I can loop over the elements in an array and remove the non-matching key from the object to achieve this, but I am trying to find if there is any shortcut or ES6 way of doing it in a single line or efficiently.

I found a couple of answers but in all cases, they are trying to compare the object with another object or array with another array but not the cross approach to compare an array with the object or vice versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the entries from `valueProvided`, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) them on whether the key is in `selectedFields`, and then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build the result object:

```js
const selectedFields = ["time", "age", "city"]

const valueProvided = {
  "time": "2022-10-01",
  "visa": "onArrival",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "paris",
  "hotel": "Holiday"
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(valueProvided).filter(([k, v]) => selectedFields.includes(k))
)

console.log(result)
```

As pointed out by @NickParsons in the comments, you can further optimise this (as long as all the keys in `selectedFields` exist in `valueProvided`) by creating an object from [`mapping`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the keys in `selectedFields` to the key, value pair from `valueProvided`:

```js
const selectedFields = ["time", "age", "city"]

const valueProvided = {
  "time": "2022-10-01",
  "visa": "onArrival",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "paris",
  "hotel": "Holiday"
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  selectedFields.map(k => [k, valueProvided[k]])
)

console.log(result)
```

If `valueProvided` was an array, you'd need to iterate that using `map`:

```js
const selectedFields = ["time", "age", "city"]

const valueProvided = [{
    "time": "2022-10-01",
    "visa": "onArrival",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "paris",
    "hotel": "Holiday"
  },
  {
    "time": "2022-11-12",
    "visa": "preBooked",
    "age": 45,
    "city": "london",
    "hotel": "Business"
  }
]

const result = valueProvided.map(v => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(v).filter(([k, v]) => selectedFields.includes(k))
  // or
  // selectedFields.map(k => [k, v[k]])
))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: We sent our answers at almost the same moment :D

Comment: Indeed, you were 2 seconds faster... :)

Comment: You could make this more efficient by removing the inner loop and instead mapping the `selectedFields` elements. Something like `Object.fromEntries(selectedFields.map(k => [k, valueProvided[k]]))`

Comment: @NickParsons indeed - you should post that as an answer. I'd definitely vote for it.

Comment: @Nick - Feel free to edit it into yours if you'd like :) I feel like it's only a slight improvement on your code/approach

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Just curious to know what if one is an `array` and another is an `array of objects`. For example what if the field `valueProvided ` was an array of objects instead of just an object? Then how can we achieve the same? Is there any shortcut for it as well?

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 please see my edit for a way to do this if `valueProvided` is an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to achieve it, I'm not sure whether this qualifies as a shortcut. Let me know:

```js
selectedFields = [ "time", "age", "city" ]
valueProvided = { "time": "2022-10-01", "visa": "onArrival", "age": 30, "city": "paris", "hotel": "Holiday" }

for (let missing of selectedFields.filter(item => (valueProvided[item] !== undefined))) {
    delete valueProvided[missing];
}

console.log(valueProvided);
```

Yes, there is a loop involved in order to remove the elements, but the search for missing elements is being done via calling `filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, although it's defenitely not the shortest answer:

```
selectedFields = [ "time", "age", "city" ];
valueProvided = { "time": "2022-10-01", "visa": "onArrival", "age": 30, "city": "paris", "hotel": "Holiday" }

console.log(valueProvided)

for (const key of Object.keys(valueProvided)) {
    if(! selectedFields.includes(key)){
      delete valueProvided[key]
    }
}
console.log(valueProvided)
```

Comment: It is mutable approach as a side note. That means you mutate the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Another "concealed loop" approach using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
valueProvided = {
  "time": "2022-10-01",
  "visa": "onArrival",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "paris",
  "hotel": "Holiday"
};

selectedFields = ["time", "age", "city"];


function pickProps(fromObject, propNames) {
  return propNames.reduce((acc, propName) => {
    acc[propName] = fromObject[propName];
    return acc
  }, {})
}

console.log(pickProps(valueProvided, selectedFields));
```

This does not mutate the source object. But like others in case property values are not of primitive types, it would reference them.

Direct mutating / re-assigment without helper function would be:

```js
var valueProvided = {
  "time": "2022-10-01",
  "visa": "onArrival",
  "age": 30,
  "city": "paris",
  "hotel": "Holiday"
};

valueProvided = ["time", "age", "city"].reduce((acc, propName) => {
  acc[propName] = valueProvided[propName];
  return acc
}, {});

console.log(valueProvided);
```

---

"Length golfing" comparison with the `fromEntries` approach:

```
result = selectedFields.reduce((a,k)=>(a[k]=valueProvided[k],a),{})
result = Object.fromEntries(selectedFields.map(k=>[k,valueProvided[k]]))
```

It also happens to be a bit faster for this use-case ([bench](https://jsbench.me/vsl98ot0mb/1)), most probably because it does not create intermediate entries array "map" but starts from "empty" result object and adds properties directly to it during reduce instead.